# Is there any way to get notifications to admin site in Django when new instances of models are created in database?

Tags: python, django, notifications, web-development-server

I am thinking of creating a website where users will add posts and basically I will check whether the posts are are valid or not in the Admin site. I was looking if it was possible to have some type of notification **inside the admin** every time someone posts or else I have to refresh the admin again and again everyday and continuously look for changes.

Any sort of alternative solutions would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this in the website itself, taking the admin to the post in the Django Admin

Comment: You can try to user Django-turbo/ Hotwire to make admin panel more SPA... that way you will have full duplex comunication using websockets.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby You mean create a separate page for admins where there will be notifications? I had this idea in my mind for a while. Thanks

Comment: I think you should use Ajax and setinterval() in JQuery.then create a model named Action or Notification.

Comment: @eisanahardani Will that show notifications inside Admin site? Or in some other custom page?